# How to fetch instagram app logged in user details in ios device using our application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, instagram

This is the first time I am working on Instagram API. If the user is already having instagram app in his device, how can we fetch his user details from our application?

Right now my app is redirecting to safari and asking the instagram credentials there though I have instagram app in my iPhone where I loggedin.

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: HI @karun Have you finished this issue can you please share sample source with us even am facing same issue..

Comment: Hi @sabir! I tried a lot for that but I didn't find any. So I am redirecting to safari in my application. I am able to post something on instagram from my application if the app is installed in the device. If you want I can share that piece of code.

Comment: can you please share the code for that .my requirement i need to fetch user details from Instagram and i need to use for sign up @karun

Comment: @sabir, I have posted it as an answer. Feel free to ask incase of any doubts.

Comment: is there any demo for that code i tried but am unable to do.if u have any demo can you please send me to my mail id:sabir.bio@gmail.com. please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @sabir, unfortunately I don't have any code example. If you are still not getting that with your code, you can send me that code to karunakar.gaming@gmail.com. So that I can help you out in fixing the issues.

Answer (score 1):

We need `Instagram.h` and `Instagram.m` file to fetch instagram user details.

You need a create an application in the Instagram developer site to get app id.

```
instagram = [[Instagram alloc] initWithClientId:APP_ID delegate:nil];

NSString *const instagramUrlScheme = @"---YourAppName---";

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {  //openo   

    if ([urlStr hasPrefix:instagramUrlScheme]) {

        //[self showAlertWithTitle:THIS_METHOD message:url.description];
        return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
    }
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {


    NSString *urlStr = url.description;    

    if ([urlStr hasPrefix:instagramUrlScheme]) {

        return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
    }

    return NO;

}
```

These are the instagram  delegates you need to implement.

```
#pragma - IGSessionDelegate

-(void)igDidLogin 
{  

    NSLog(@"Instagram did login");


    //[[self appDelegate] showAlertWithTitle:@"igDidLogin" message:@""];

    // here i can store accessToken

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self appDelegate].instagram.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    //NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"users/self/followed-by", @"method", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"users/self", @"method", nil];

    [[self appDelegate].instagram requestWithParams:params
                                       delegate:self];

}

-(void)igDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled 
{    

    NSLog(@"Instagram did not login");

    NSString* message = nil;

    if (cancelled) {
        message = @"Access cancelled!";
    }

    else {
        message = @"Access denied!";
    }

    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

}

-(void)igDidLogout 
{   

    NSLog(@"Instagram did logout");
    // remove the accessToken
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"accessToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

-(void)igSessionInvalidated 
{   

    NSLog(@"Instagram session was invalidated");

}
```

You have to use these when you want to connect to instagram.

```
[self appDelegate].instagram.accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
[self appDelegate].instagram.sessionDelegate = self;    

[[self appDelegate].instagram logout];
[[self appDelegate].instagram authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"comments", @"likes", nil]];
```

Hope this helps:

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge when we are redirecting from our app to other app we can't access the other app details (Login details).

Answer (score 0):

As long as I also do know, this is not possible.

We can't get details of the other app from our app.

You can get more info for instagram by this instagram developer [link](http://instagram.com/developer/#).

Hope this helps you.